# Python strings with anagrams

Tags: python, string, anagram

At the moment this code takes in a string from a user and compares it to a text file in which many words are stored. It then outputs all the words that contain an exact match to the string. (E.G "otp = opt, top, pot) Currently when i input the string it only matches the string to the word with the EXACT same letters in a rearranged order.

My question is how do i go about being able to type in excess letters but still output all the words that are contained? for example: Type in "orkignwer" and the program will output "working" even though there are extra letters.

```
words = []


def isAnAnagram(word, user):
    wordList= list(word)
    wordList.sort()
    inputList= list(user)
    inputList.sort()
    return (wordList == inputList)

def getAnagrams(user):
    lister = [word for word in words if len(word) == len(user) ]
    for item in lister:
        if isAnAnagram(item, user):
            yield item


with open('Dictionary.txt', 'r') as f:
    allwords = f.readlines()
f.close()

for x in allwords:
    x = x.rstrip()
    words.append(x)
inp = 1


while inp != "99":
    inp = input("enter word:")
    result = getAnagrams(inp)
    print(list(result))
```

Comment: You will likely want to use a `Counter` and then check that the input word has all the same letters (`a.keys() == b.keys()`) and that each letter has higher or equal counts `b[k] > v for k, v in a.items()`.

Comment: Aside: remember there's no need to `close` the file when using `with`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit the `isAnAnagram` and the `getAnagrams` functions. First the `getAnagrams` function should be edited to also include the words of greater length in the `lister` list:

```
def getAnagrams(user):
    lister = [word for word in words if len(word) <= len(user) ]
    for item in lister:
        if isAnAnagram(item, user):
            yield item
```

Then you would need to edit the `isAnAnagram` function. As Alexander Huszagh pointed out, you can use the Counter from the `collections` package:

```
from collections import Counter

def isAnAnagram(word, user):
    word_counter = Counter(word)
    input_counter = Counter(user)
    return all(count <= input_counter[key] for key, count in word_counter.items())
```

The `all(count <= input_counter[key] for key, count in word_counter.items())` checks to see if every letter of `word` appears in `user` at least as many times as they did in `word`.

P.S. If you want a more optimized solution, you might want to checkout TRIEs (e.g. MARISA-trie, python-trie or PyTrie).

Comment: Thanks everyone. I used your code changes bbkglb but it still does not output what i need. What i need is, for example,  if i typed in "tpozxc" the prog would realise that there are 3 words in this and output "opt, top ,pot"
but what is happening is it is ONLY outputting strings that match exactly in a re-arranged order, so to get top opt and pot i need to enter in a string with ONLY a combination of those letters.

Comment: @CBren Oh I see, I misunderstood your question then; I edited both of the functions. This should fix it.